# Connecting to server from PC having two IP addresses

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I'm developing a windows application using VB.NET 2017, I need to connect to a web service on a server.

If the PC where the win app is running has two IP addresses, how to know using which IP address the win app connected to the web service?

I need to know that from the win app itself.

Comment: How are you consuming the web service? At some point in the mix of objects used to connect to it, depending on how, exactly, you are consuming it, there should be endpoints representing your side and the server's side, giving you a starting point to obtain the IP of your consuming connection.

Comment: I'm adding service reference in visual studio to the web service.

Comment: If that's how you're consuming it, that's using WCF.

Comment: So how to know using which IP the connection happened, from the win app?

Comment: Without seeing exactly how you are connecting to the service, we can't give you an exact answer. That's why I offered the generic comment; the IP used by your client will be exposed, somehow, via the code that you use to consume the service. The *exact syntax* of that depends on how you are consuming the service. Post some code that shows how you are consuming the web service.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  I closed this as a duplicate when I think what you are asking is how to find out which address it's using, rather than specifying which one it should use.  In any case, you might find the info in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249846/specify-the-outgoing-ip-address-to-use-with-wcf-client) helpful.

Comment: There's also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0) which is probably more applicable

Comment: Or even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332575/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-binding-that-my-client-proxy-is-using)